# Getting selected value from <apex:inputField> (dropdown) to a controller variable

Tags: picklist, controller-extension, inputfield

I am working on a custom VF page for a case screen with extension controller class in use.

```
<apex:actionRegion >
  <apex:inputfield label="Action" value="{!case.Action__c}" id="Action" >
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="ProdFamilyModel" immediate="false" /> 
  </apex:inputfield> 
</apex:actionRegion>
```

I want the selected value from the input field assigned to a string variable in my extension class. I have searched a lot and was unable to get an answer.

Suppose in my dropdown there are two values, say "Apple","Orange". So if i select Apple, i want this name to be stores in a string variable.

Answer (score 3):

You put the variable you want to store this value in as your `value="{!SomeString}"` attribute.

You'll need to pass the value over to the record somewhere, usually in a save method, or in whatever action your `actionSupport` is calling.

You could even add a method to set a variable and call it with your `actionSupport`.

---

Seems like what you need is a reference to your case object inside your extension class.

I've prepared a demo page & class to show some of the methods of saving references to various objects.

Examples (Noted with Comments)

1. Save the controller reference. By keeping the variable you take as a parameter for your extension, you can call other methods, such as `getRecord()` to obtain information you don't have direct access too. This lets you call `save()` as well.
2. Keep a reference to the record used on the page. In your constructor, you use `getRecord()` to keep a reference saved of the object. Any updates should be carried over to your reference, allowing you to access field values & preform actions to the sObject. You can also use this object instead of the object provided by the standard controller, but this isn't always advisable.
3. Use a variable to keep track of input values. Saving the input to a variable allows you to do conditional validation or rerendering without accessing your records fields, until you need to save the record. You'll probably still need a reference to the standard controller to modify & save the record.

## Demo Class

```
public class DemoClass {

    // Example #1 
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; set; }

    // Example #2 
    public Account Record { get; set; }

    // Example #3 
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public DemoClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller; // Save controller reference to access record 
        this.Record = (Account)this.controller.getRecord(); // Save reference to actual record to manipulate fields in controller 
    }

    public PageReference CustomSave() {
        // Keep only a value saved, and carry this value over to the record on save 
        // Still requires a controller reference
        if (Value != null) {
            controller.getRecord().put('Name', Value);
        }

        return controller.Save(); 
    }

}
```

## Demo Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DemoClass">

    <apex:Form>

        <!-- Example #1 --> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />

        <!-- Example #2 --> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!Record.Name}" />

        <!-- Example #3 --> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!Value}" />

        <apex:commandButton action="{!CustomSave}" value="Custom Save" />

    </apex:Form>
</apex:page>
```

---

Based on the code posted, I think the easist thing to do would be to keep a reference to the standard controller in your code, and add a string variable with a getter which fetches your value.

Like so:

```
public class Demo {

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; set; }

    public String Action {
        get {
            return (String)controller.getRecord().get('Action__c');
        }
    }

    public DemoClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller; // Save controller reference to access record 
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you need the value, you can use `{!Action}`. That being said, you could also just directly access the field value if you're trying to put a value onto a page (`{!Case.Action__c}`)

Comment: The 'value' attribute is already present as you can see in the code snippet in the question which is used to load the values of the Action__c picklist. Where else can i give a 'value' attribute to get the selected value?

Comment: I'm saying you can use a value that isn't a case field for your picklist, and then carry the value over to the record when you save. Could also use the getter of a variable to pull the value from the case record & access it. Something like `get { return Case.Action__c; }`

Comment: From your other comments, it seems like you're writing an extension to a page which is using the standard case controller, and don't have a reference to the case variable itself, which complicates things slightly. Can you [edit] your question to include the rest of your controller, or at least however much is relevant? Seeing some of your other variables would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers. At last i am able to get it done.

Answer (score 3):

I am extending @battery.cord's answer with an example as follows:

Visualforce

```
<apex:actionRegion >
  <apex:inputfield label="Action" value="{!caseObj.Action__c}" id="Action" >
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="ProdFamilyModel" action="{!passValueToController}" /> 
  </apex:inputfield> 
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Controller

```
public class ActionSupportController
{
    public String fieldValue {get; set;}
    public Case caseObj {get;set;}
    public void passValueToController()   
    {        
          fieldValue = caseObj.Action__c; //this will assign the selected value to Controller variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i tried this method, but got an error as `Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String`  when Action_c is assigned to a string variable. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `Case`? If not, Salesforce will think you're referencing the type `Case`, and provide the field schema for `Action__c` instead of a field value.

Comment: updates my answer, with proper variable `caseObj`

Comment: @SantanuBoral  After researching with your code i was successfully able to assign the selected value to the string variable. Thank you for leading me to the right direction.

Comment: You should select one best answer since your problem got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to get the selected value from inputfield dropdown with the help of @battery.cord and @Santanu Boral.

This answer might help others who are stuck in the same problem.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="Inputfld">
 <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Case Edit" mode="edit">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Action" columns="2" collapsible="false" >

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Action" for="Action"/>
               <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputfield label="Action" value="{!Case.Action__c}" id="Action" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="ProdFamilyModel" immediate="false" action="{!passValueToController}"/> 
                    </apex:inputfield>  
               </apex:actionRegion>  
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputPanel id="ProdFamilyModel" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(case.Action__c == 'Password Reset', true, false)}">
                        <apex:inputField id="Password"  value="{!case.Password__c}"  rendered="{!IF(case.Action__c == 'Password Reset', true, false)}"/>   
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(case.Action__c == 'Pin Reset', true, false)}">
                        <apex:inputField id="Pin" value="{!case.Pin__c}" rendered="{!IF(case.Action__c == 'Pin Reset', true, false)}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!IF(case.Action__c == 'Replacement Card', true, false)}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!case.Replacement_Card__c}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>

     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class

```
public class Inputfld {
 Case thisCase;
public String selectedAction{get;set;}
public String fieldValue {get; set;}

 public Inputfld(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
 {
    thisCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();
    System.debug('thisCase.Action__c====='+thisCase.Action__c);
}
public void passValueToController()   
{        
    fieldValue = thisCase.Action__c; 
    System.debug('fieldValue ====='+fieldValue);// This will provide the selected value form the action dropdown.
}
```

}